# Content Security Policy self blocking inline

Tags: javascript, html, inline, content-security-policy, inline-scripting

In my experience, the header below, when enabled, blocks inline script on the page.

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'`.

Why is inline code not considered "self"?

I know I can use nonce or other work arounds to allow inline, or move to external files. I'm just interested to know why inline code isn't considered self.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Not allowing inline scripts prevents a common vulnerability. See [Why It's Bad to Use 'unsafe-inline' in script-src](https://csper.io/blog/no-more-unsafe-inline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default inline code is disabled, not just because of `default-src 'self'`. To enabled inline code one has to use `unsafe-inline` in `script-src`